# Connect AWS CodeDeploy to Github without using my Github user?

Tags: amazon-web-services, github, aws-code-deploy

AWS documentation describes how you authenticate to Github using your browser, and that you're currently logged into Github as a valid user with permission to the repository you want to deploy from:

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/codedeploy/latest/userguide/github-integ.html#github-integ-behaviors-auth

Is there any way to setup CodeDeploy without linking my user and having a browser? I'd love to do this using webhooks on each repository and AWS API calls, but I'll make a Github 'service user' if I have to.

More examples:
http://blogs.aws.amazon.com/application-management/post/Tx33XKAKURCCW83/Automatically-Deploy-from-GitHub-Using-AWS-CodeDeploy

I'd love to use webhooks on my repo, or set them up myself, than permit AWS access to every repository on my Github account.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There does not appear to be an alternative to doing the OAuth flow in your browser at this point. If you're concerned about opening your whole Github account up to Amazon, creating a service user is probably the best approach, unfortunately it seems this user still needs administrative access to your repos to set up the integration.

Answer (score 1):

After more research I realized my first answer is wrong, you can use AWS CLI to create a CodePipeline using a Github OAuth token. Then you can plug in your CodeDeploy deployment from there. Here's an example configuration:

```
{
    "pipeline": {
        "roleArn": "arn:aws:iam::99999999:role/AWS-CodePipeline-Service",
        "stages": [
            {
                "name": "Source", 
                "actions": [
                    {
                        "inputArtifacts": [], 
                        "name": "Source", 
                        "actionTypeId": {
                            "category": "Source", 
                            "owner": "ThirdParty", 
                            "version": "1", 
                            "provider": "GitHub"
                        }, 
                        "outputArtifacts": [
                            {
                                "name": "MyApp"
                            }
                        ], 
                        "configuration": {
                            "Owner": "myusername", 
                            "Repo": "myrepo", 
                            "Branch": "master", 
                            "OAuthToken": "**************"
                        }, 
                        "runOrder": 1
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                "name": "Beta",
                "actions": [
                    {
                        "inputArtifacts": [
                            {
                                "name": "MyApp"
                            }
                        ],
                        "name": "CodePipelineDemoFleet",
                        "actionTypeId": {
                            "category": "Deploy",
                            "owner": "AWS",
                            "version": "1",
                            "provider": "CodeDeploy"
                        },
                        "outputArtifacts": [],
                        "configuration": {
                            "ApplicationName": "CodePipelineDemoApplication",
                            "DeploymentGroupName": "CodePipelineDemoFleet"
                        },
                        "runOrder": 1
                    }
                ]
            }
        ],
        "artifactStore": {
            "type": "S3",
            "location": "codepipeline-us-east-1-99999999"
        },
        "name": "MySecondPipeline",
        "version": 1
    }
}
```

You can create the pipeline using the command:

```
aws codepipeline create-pipeline --cli-input-json file://input.json
```

Make sure that the Github OAuth token has permissions `admin:repo_hook` and `repo`.

Reference: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/codepipeline/create-pipeline.html

Comment: I think this would be using a different product at this point, though. It seems like the answer is still "with AWS CodeDeploy, you can't."

Answer (score 0):

CodeDeploy and Github integration works based on Github Oauth. So to use the CodeDeploy and Github integration, you will have to trust CodeDeploy github application using your github account. Currently this integration will only work in your browser with a valid github account cause CodeDeploy application will always redirect back to CodeDeploy console to verify&finish the OAuth authentication process.

Answer (score -3):

You can do it using this `bash` command

FROM LOCAL TO REMOTE

`rsync --delete -azvv -e "ssh -i /path/to/pem" /path/to/local/code/* ubuntu@66.66.66.66:/path/to/remote/code`

FROM REMOTE TO LOCAL

`rsync --delete -azvv -e "ssh -i /path/to/pem" ubuntu@66.66.66.66:/path/to/remote/code/* /path/to/local/code`

`rsync` checks file versions and updates the files that need to be update

Comment: Yes. He asked to deploy without a github user

Comment: I asked how to use the AWS CodeDeploy product without a Github user, while still using the integration they provide with Github. Your answer doesn't really make sense in this context.

Comment: Ok. I just offered an alternative.
And no, there's no way to avoid that unless you use a direct push method, like `rsync`

Comment: You can't rsync to CodeDeploy directly either. It's an orchestration tool, not a filesystem.

Comment: No. rsync is for circumventing CodeDeploy and not using your Git user. The only way to NOT use it

Comment: This is a question asking for a solution using CodeDeploy and Github webhooks instead of a Github user (not Git, but specifically Github). You're basically saying "use this whole other toolchain." That's not helpful as it doesn't address the question. I'm not even asking for a tool for transferring files.